# When Call Angular function from JavaScript function but its showing undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to call Angular function from JavaScript function but its showing undefined.

> I Created One Demo Example Here As Follow:

```
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { GetSelectedProductService } from '../ServiceOfService/get-selected-product.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


function process(){
..
..

 this.processDone(response);

   //when i call from here to processDone function, its showing 'undefined exception'. 
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-process',
  templateUrl: './payment-process.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-process.component.css']
})
export class PaymentProcessComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit(): void { }


    processDone(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.` will not work as long you are out of the class-scope.

Comment: You can put a call like `this.processDone(...);` inside your `ngOnInit` for instance, but not in some arbitrary function outside of your Component class. If you want to refactor your code like that, you have to pass the scope object to your `process` function.

Comment: how I pass the scope object to process function

Comment: Why would you write a stand-alone function to call Angular Component's method? Can you explain in detail what exactly the process method is doing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot call your Component's function outside of the component. You have to put it inside of the Component.

What's unclear is how you are calling `process` to begin with, so you probably need to clear that out.

```
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { GetSelectedProductService } from '../ServiceOfService/get-selected-product.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-process',
  templateUrl: './payment-process.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-process.component.css']
})
export class PaymentProcessComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() {}

   ngOnInit(): void { }


   processDone(response){
     console.log(response);
   }
   
   process(){
     ..
     ..
     this.processDone(response);
   }
}
```